# How do the Gopikas know that Krishna is Devaki and Vasudeva's son?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, yashoda

Krishna, the son of Devaki and Vasudeva, is brought up in Gokula, and later Vrindavana, as the son of Nanda and Yashoda. Later Akrura, a Vrishni, comes and reveals to Yashoda and Nanda (and the rest of Vrindavana) that Krsna is actually the son of Devaki and Vasudeva, a Yadava Prince destined to end Kamsa's reign. This is generally visualized as a highly emotional scene, where many gopis are distraught and lamenting their fate.

But just a few days (or weeks) before, during the Rasa Leela, they sing the Gopika Gita, a gem of a prayer. In this prayer, which you can [read here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/31), the gopikas sing:

> Na Khalu Gopikanandano Bhavan Akhiladehinam Antaratma Drk 
>   Vikhanasarthito Vishvaguptaye, Sakha Udeyivaan Satvatam Kule
>
> "You are not actually the son of the gopī Yaśodā, O friend, but rather the indwelling witness in the hearts of all embodied souls. Because Lord Brahmā prayed for You to come and protect the universe, You have now appeared in the Sātvata dynasty.

Earlier too, in the song known as [Venu Gita](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/21), they say,

> Vrndavanam Sakhi Bhuvo vVtanoti Kirtim
>   Yad **Devaki Suta** Padambuja Labdha Lakshmih
>
> "O friend, Vṛndāvana is spreading the glory of the earth, having obtained the treasure of the lotus feet of Kṛṣṇa, the son of Devakī."

So, how do the gopikas know beforehand that Krsna is a son of Devaki and Vasudeva?

Comment: Why do some people write Krshna for Krishna?what significance does it carry?

Comment: @Rickross No significance. It is just the diatrical way of writing. And I like that spelling

Comment: Perhaps Krishna told the Gopis his true identity, and perhaps the Gopis were upset that this was now public knowledge and that Krishna was going to leave them.

Comment: @Keshav Speculation.... It can be so, but then why would Krsna say that?

Comment: @Surya Well, love is based on trust, and he may have wanted to confide in them everything about him, both his divinity and the purpose of his incarnation on Earth.  Or he could have revealed that information to them as a reward for their Bhakti.

Comment: @Keshav Find the proper answer, speculation is not encouraged... :P :P

Comment: @Keshav Also check [this question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11164/what-happened-to-vasudevas-and-his-brothers-horde-of-children) related to the Yadava dynasty (why don't we have a tag for it?).

Comment: @Surya For tag requests, you can post an answer on meta [here](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/470/2995).

Comment: Great question! I have never come across any text that mentions explicitly Krishna's disclosing this secret to Gopis. Come to think of it the secret was Nand baba's no one else should have known it not even Yashoda!

Comment: @Dr. Actually even Nanda was unaware of this secret. He seems to take it pretty sportingly though.

Comment: Yes can't imagine how Nand & Yashoda would have felt after having to let go of their son. Balarama at least was known as Vasudev and Rohini's son so that may have been different but finding about Krishna not being their own child would have been a heartbreak of sorts..

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that gopis knew that Krishna took birth as Devaki's son and thus they may be speaking this way.

Another way to understand:

Vishwanath Chakravarty Thakur, a Gaudiya Vaishnava Acharya quotes from Vishnu Purana in Sarartha Darsini commentary of Srimad Bhagavatam to SB 10.21.10:

> dve nāmnī nanda-bhāryāyā  yaśodā devakīti ca ataḥ sakhyam abhūt tasya
>    devakyā śauri-jāyayā
>
> “The wife of Nanda had two names, Yaśodā and also Devakī. Therefore it
>   was natural that she [the wife of Nanda] develop friendship with
>   Devakī, the wife of Śauri [Vasudeva].”

Thus here son of Devaki could mean son of Yasoda.

Regarding SB 10.31.4 where Gopis say Krishna as not son of Yasoda,

Vishwanath Chakravarty Thakur explains it in two different ways:

First he explains 10.31.3 :

> If you want to kill us, then why did you repeatedly save us from
>   danger? It is not proper to save us and then kill us. You saved us
>   from the water of the lake filled with Kaliya’s poison.  You saves us
>   from the vicious man eater, Aghasura  the snake (vyala raksasa). You
>   saved us from the rain poured down by Indra (varsadi).  You saved us
>   from Trnavarata (marut), from Indra’s thunderbolt, from the bull demon
>   Aristasura (vrsa), from Vyomasura (mayatmaja), from some many types of
>   fear (visvato). O best of men (rsabha) by killing the demons, by your
>   personal protection,  we,  who have only you as  our life, were saved.
>   Though you protected  all of vraja from the rain and other calamities,
>   you also protected us. Putting our faith in you as our protector, we
>   come to you for relieving us of the pain of being pierced by the five
>   arrows of cupid, otherwise we will die in the flames of separation
>   from you which are thousands of times more intense. Do you not fear
>   the sin of killing our faith?”

Then he comments on 10.31.4:

First Explanation:

> “O gopis, you speak without thoroughly investigating. I, son of Nanda,
>   am the source of all bliss.  You accuse me of the sin of killing women
>   and destroying faith. Therefore, I will leave this place and hide
>   myself so that for many births you will not see me.”  Fearing such
>   response from Krsna, the repentant gopis began to praise him in order
>   to please him.  “You are  not the son of a cowherd woman, but rather
>   the soul within each jiva, the form of Vasudeva who inspires the
>   heart, who witnesses  everything (drk).  We have heard this from
>   Baguri and Paurnamasi. Thus we speak under inspiration from you.
>   Therefore do not be angry with us,  but be pleased with us.  We have
>   also heard about the cause for your appearance. Please  hear that.
>   Because Brahma  (vikhanas) prayed for you to protect the universe
>   (visva guptaye), you appeared in the womb of Yasoda.”

He gives an alternate explanation as follows:

> “One cannot find the such suffering of the gopis  among all men,
>   devatas, animals or birds, yet seeing our suffering you are blissful.
>   Therefore we conclude, you did not appear in the womb of Yasoda, who
>   is sensitive to a  particle of suffering in others. We do not see  any
>   of her good qualities in you.” “Then who am I?”   “We think you are
>   the   soul pervading all entities (antaryami). The antaryami,  though 
>   seeing all the sufferings of the jivas, resides there in the heart
>   very comfortably. We do not know the reason for your appearing in this
>   world, as you are so indifferent. Brahma, desiring the increase in the
>   creation, prayed “Stay hidden (visva guptaye), because if you revealed
>   yourself,  all  the jivas will get liberated by devotion to you, and
>   will leave the universe.   Though you appear, remain hidden, so that 
>   no one understands that you are  the supreme Lord.    What  to speak
>   of ordinary men, who disregard you as  the Lord in your human like
>   pastimes, even those surrendered to you will take on the role of
>   demons (lika Jarasandha). Thus I will be able to carry out the
>   creation.